# Gmail api get message sent or received

Tags: php, json, laravel, gmail-api

How do I find out whether a message ( returned from a [get message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) endpoint ) is sent or received?

Here is the message resource:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "internalDate": long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}
```

I've inspected the Payload with `getPayload()` and headers `getPayload()->getHeaders()` But do not see anything that indicates whether the message was sent or received.

Comment: You may check the [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) that let you watch for changes to Gmail mailboxes. Then use the [`Users: watch`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) method which set up or update a push notification watch on the given user mailbox.

Comment: You can check if the `labelIds` has the label `SENT`. `$is_sent = in_array('SENT', $message->getLabelIds());`

Comment: @Tholle can you post this as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `labelIds` has the label `SENT`:

```
$is_sent = in_array('SENT', $message->getLabelIds());
```